# Need SQL for an overview of invoices

Tags: sql-server

I have tables:

- invoices(factuur) with aa. ID,amount,date,removed
- payments(journaal) with aa. invoiceID, debet,credit,date,payed
- second payments (dbetalingen) with aa. invoiceID,date,amount,payed (yes/no)

I have made this query:

```
select 
    dfactuur.factuurid, 
    isnull(jnaf,0)+isnull(oldafschr,0) afgeschr,
    isnull(fbetaald,0)+isnull(oldbetaald,0)betaald,
    bedrag,
    betalingen.datum,
    dfactuur.datum, 
    cast(sum(isnull((isnull(betalingen.credit,0)/dfactuur.bedrag)*cast(betalingen.datum-dfactuur.datum as integer),0))/count(*)as integer) dagen 
from 
    dfactuur 
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            factuurid,
            ISNULL(Sum(credit),0)-ISNULL(Sum(debet),0)As FBetaald,
            datum,
            credit
        FROM 
            journaal 
        WHERE 
            Soort=1 AND 
            betaald=1
        GROUP BY 
            credit,
            datum,
            factuurid) 
        As betalingen 
        ON betalingen.factuurid=Dfactuur.factuurid 
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            factuurid,
            ISNULL(Sum(credit),0)-ISNULL(Sum(debet),0)As JNAf 
        FROM 
            journaal 
        WHERE 
            Soort=1 AND 
            ISNULL(betaald,0)=0 
        GROUP BY 
            factuurid)
        As afschrijvingen ON afschrijvingen.factuurid=Dfactuur.factuurid
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            factuurid , 
            ISNULL(Sum(bedrag),0) As OldBetaald 
        FROM 
            DBetaling 
        WHERE 
            betaald=1 
        GROUP BY 
            factuurid)
        As Oldbetalingen ON Oldbetalingen.factuurid=Dfactuur.factuurid
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            factuurid, 
            ISNULL(Sum(bedrag),0) As OldAfschr 
        FROM 
            DBetaling 
        WHERE 
            ISNULL(betaald,0)=0 
        GROUP BY factuurid)
        As OldAfschr ON OldAfschr.factuurid=Dfactuur.factuurid
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            factuurid, 
            count(*) Herh 
        FROM 
            Herhaling 
        GROUP BY 
            factuurid) 
        As Herhalingen ON Herhalingen.factuurid=dfactuur.factuurid
WHERE 
    ISNULL(verwijderd,0)=0 AND 
    dfactuur.relatienr = 1329--1284
GROUP BY 
    dfactuur.factuurid,
    afschrijvingen.jnaf,
    OldAfschr.OldAfschr,
    betalingen.fbetaald,
    Oldbetalingen.oldbetaald,
    bedrag,
    betalingen.datum,
    dfactuur.datum
```

this results in many records and when more payments are made on one invoice the records appears more then once.

I need a query which returns 1 record with:
number of invoices total and not fully paid, total amount of all invoices, total amount paid, total amount written of, and avarige days of payments.

I don't need dfactuur.factuurid

Comment: Please edit to include sample data from the tables and the output you want to obtain from that sample data.

Comment: How many records do you have in tables Journaal and DBetaling. With that many self joins, the query will die for large tables. Also include sample data for the tables and the output.  Which field refers to invoices? Help us with some English translation of those field names.

Comment: Ken, do you meen the design of the table or records (how do I send records)
Emacs, that can be over 100,000 records, the result scans maybe a few hundred
The query above does work fine
Bedrag: amount
betaald: payed
afschrijving: write off
datum: date

Comment: But the query returns a number of records which a have to proces and this makes it slow.
Does someone know a solution??